# Inheritance with local classes

Tags: java, scopes, local-class

So i was working with local classes this morning when I encountered a strange behaviour of inheritance regarding scopes.

```
public class Foo{
    public void printer(){
        class Hello extends Bar{
           private String str = "Hello";
        }

        class World extends Hello{
           private void print(){
              System.out.println(super.str);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

With class Bar looking like this:

```
public class Bar{
   protected String str = "FooBar";
}
```

So i expected an ouput like this:

```
FooBar
```

But ended up with:

```
Hello
```

Shouldn't the private prefix of the String declaration prevent the child class from accessing the variable?

However I procceded further and removed the String declaration and this time ended up with my previous expected ouput.

So why doesn't it always get the variable of class Bar when a variable of the same name is declared private in the direct parent class?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You should show your main method for how you ran this

Comment: By calling this line: `System.out.println(super.str);`
You're actually calling super class of World, which is the Hello class.

Comment: @sovas I think that was understood already. The expected output was that of the `Bar` class

Comment: *Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field*... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, I knew this part of the tutorial. I was just kind of confused why the ´private´ declaration doesn't bypass this rule. But the Post shmosel linked was more or less the explanation i searched for but didn't found. :)

Comment: The `private` doesn't stop the fact that you are shadowing the field. If you want to override the value, you'd use methods.